# Draw background for each cell in ObjectListField

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde

I am creating a blackberry apllication which pre-dominantly uses ObjectListFields..All i need now is to draw an image as a background for each cell. I know this is quiet possible but i am not getting hold of the procedure. if i draw bitmap in drawlistrow() function the bluehighlight gets into the background and the cell highlight becomes very hard to read......can anybody help me with a code snippet to get through this problem ....thanks...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601887/how-do-you-make-a-dropdown-list-that-displays-images-to-the-user-instead-of-text

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know ObjectListFields focus fills the background of the element blue and alters the foreground color (text) to white.
If you really need to draw an image on the background, you should at least change the foreground color to a high contrast or at make the background image transparent.

Check the style of the graphics in drawListRow with 
`graphics.isDrawingStyleSet(Graphics.DRAWSTYLE_FOCUS)`and set different colors for them.